# How do I iterate through a dataframe using nested for loop using python2.7 and append to a new dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate through two python dataframe columns to determine specific values and then add the results to a new column.  The code below is throwing the following error:

```
raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')"
```

I'm not sure why?

Dataframe:

```
    TeamID    todayorno
1   sw        True
2   pr        False
3   sw        False
4   pr        True
```

Code:

```
team = []

for row in results['TeamID']:   
    if row == "sw":
        for r in results['todayorno']:
            if r == True:
                team.append('red')
            else:
                team.append('green')
    else:
        team.append('green')

results['newnew'] = team
```

Comment: You gave an example of how the dataframe looks before your code runs. Can you give an example of how you _want_ the dataframe to look _after_ your code runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating your dataframe twice, indicated by the fact you have 2 `for` loops. You end up with a result of 10 items instead of the required 4.

Explicit iteration is not required. You can use `numpy.select` to apply values for specified conditions.

```
import numpy as np

mask = results['TeamID'] == 'sw'
conditions = [~mask, mask & results['todayorno'], mask & ~results['todayorno']]
values = ['green', 'red', 'green']

results['newnew'] = np.select(conditions, values, 'green')

print(results)

  TeamID  todayorno newnew
1     sw       True    red
2     pr      False  green
3     sw      False  green
4     pr       True  green
```

Comment: Thank you jpp!  This is working exactly as intended.  I'm going to be reading up on numpy! :D

Comment: can you explain how this line works?    conditions = [~mask, mask & results['todayorno'], mask & ~results['todayorno']] ---- let me take a stab:  are you selecting all inverse of the mask, mask with todayorno, and mask with inverse selection of todayorno?  then assigning the same order as green, red, green?

Comment: `~` means negative, `&` means "and" or "intersection". Each item of `conditions` matches to an item in `values`. For example, `~mask` matches with `'green'` (the first element in each list).

Answer (score 0):

## Quick answer

Don't try to loop.

Instead, create the new column with a default value (i.e. the most common), and then address the values you want to change and set them:

```
>>> results
  TeamID  todayorno
0     sw       True
1     pr      False
2     sw      False
3     pr       True
>>> results['newnew'] = 'green'
>>> results
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
0     sw       True  green
1     pr      False  green
2     sw      False  green
3     pr       True  green
>>> results.loc[(results['TeamID'] == 'sw') & (results['todayorno']), 'newnew'] = 'red'
>>> results
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
0     sw       True    red
1     pr      False  green
2     sw      False  green
3     pr       True  green
```

Alternatively, you can use `.apply(..., index=1)` to calculate a whole series with a function that looks at each row, and assign the whole series at once as a column:

```
>>> results
  TeamID  todayorno
0     sw       True
1     pr      False
2     sw      False
3     pr       True
>>> results['newnew'] = results.apply(
...     lambda s: 'red' if s['TeamID'] == 'sw' and s['todayorno'] else 'green',
...     axis=1,
... )
>>> results
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
0     sw       True    red
1     pr      False  green
2     sw      False  green
3     pr       True  green
```

## Explanation

### The problem

As far as I can tell from your code, you're trying to Add a column to your dataframe called `newnew`.

In the rows of the dataframe where the `TeamID` column contains the value `"sw"` and the column `todayorno` contains the value `True`, you want the column `newnew` to contain the value `"red"`.

In all other rows, you want the value of `newnew` to be `"green"`.

### A rule

To work efficiently with pandas, a very important rule is: don't try to loop. Especially through the rows.

Instead get pandas to do the work for you.

So, the first step is to create the new column. And since in most cases you want the value to be `"green"`, you can simply do:

```
results['newnew'] = 'green'
```

Now your dataframe looks like:

```
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
0     sw       True  green
1     pr      False  green
2     sw      False  green
3     pr       True  green
```

You'll notice that pandas "expanded" the single value provided through all the rows.

Now to get the `sw/True` rows to be `"red"`, first you need to locate them all. For this we need to understand how pandas addressing work.

### (A little bit of) How pandas addressing works

When you use square brackets after a pandas dataframe, you are, in general, addressing the columns of your dataframe. Ex:

```
>>> results['TeamID']
0    sw
1    pr
2    sw
3    pr
Name: TeamID, dtype: object
```

I.e. by requesting the `TeamID` index of the `results` dataframe, you got back a `Series` called `TeamID` containing only the values of that column.

On the other hand, if you want to address rows, you need to use the `.loc` property.

```
>>> results.loc[1]
TeamID          pr
todayorno    False
newnew       green
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Here we got back a `Series` containing the values of the row.

If we want to see multiple rows, we can get a sub-dataframe by indexing a list of rows:

```
>>> results.loc[[1,2]]
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
1     pr      False  green
2     sw      False  green
```

Or by using a condition:

```
>>> results.loc[results['TeamID'] == 'pr']
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
1     pr      False  green
3     pr       True  green
```

The condition can contain boolean combinations, but the syntax for that has special requirements, like using `&` instead of `and` and carefully wrapping the parts of the condition with parentheses due to the precedence of the `&` operator:

```
>>> results.loc[(results['TeamID'] == 'sw') & (results['todayorno'])]
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
1     sw       True  green
```

The `.loc` property can also address by both rows and columns. A comma separates the addressing parts where the addressing of rows comes first and the columns last:

```
>>> results.loc[results['TeamID'] == 'pr', 'todayorno']
1    False
3     True
Name: todayorno, dtype: bool
```

### The final touch

And the `.loc` property can be used for assignments as well, by assigning the value you want to the desired "coordinates".

So in your case:

```
>>> results.loc[
...     (results['TeamID'] == 'sw') & (results['todayorno']),
...     'newnew'
... ] = "red"
>>> results
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
0     sw       True    red
1     pr      False  green
2     sw      False  green
3     pr       True  green
```

### The other solution

The `.apply()` method of dataframes allows applying a single function multiple times, either column-wise or row-wise. To apply row-wise, pass the `axis=1` parameter.

If the result of the function passed to `.apply(..., axis=1)` returns a single value, then the result of each application of the function will be combined in a Series with the same *addressing* (the same *index*, in pandas parlance) of the rows of the dataframe.

So:

```
>>> results.apply(
...     lambda s: 'red' if s['TeamID'] == 'sw' and s['todayorno'] else 'green',
...     axis=1,
... )
0      red
1    green
2    green
3    green
dtype: object
```

This can then be assigned as a column of the dataframe:

```
>>> results['newnew'] = results.apply(
...     lambda s: 'red' if s['TeamID'] == 'sw' and s['todayorno'] else 'green',
...     axis=1,
... )
>>> results
  TeamID  todayorno newnew
0     sw       True    red
1     pr      False  green
2     sw      False  green
3     pr       True  green
```

Comment: Note `pd.Series.apply` + `lambda` should be used as a *very last resort* where vectorised solutions are not possible. It is far more efficient to use Boolean series for indexing than row-wise ternary statements.